# Jsoup extract multi images sources

Tags: jsoup

I work on  [this link](http://deals.souq.com/sa-ar/?id_tag=48)  to extract image's src

I tried this code and it extracted all images with their tags

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://deals.souq.com/sa-ar/?id_tag=48").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div.padt-10 img")
```

Now I want to extract images with their src only, I tried with following code but It extracted the source of the first image only.

```
System.out.println(doc.select("div.padt-10 img").attr("src")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the source code.
This `doc.select("div.padt-10 img")` returns `Elements`. The implementation of `attr` in `Elements` is this

```
public String attr(String attributeKey) {
    for (Element element : contents) {
        if (element.hasAttr(attributeKey))
            return element.attr(attributeKey);
    }
    return "";
}
```

As you can see, this will return immediately after the first valid match.
If you want all the urls you can use this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://deals.souq.com/sa-ar/?id_tag=48").get();
Elements imgs = doc.select("div.padt-10 img");
for(Element im : imgs)
    System.out.println(im.attr("src"));
```

Comment: It's possible without loop?